# How can I Consume a Soap message with Namespace from salesforce in PHP

Tags: php, xml, salesforce

I am new to salesforce.  Proficient in php but I haven't done any xml parsing.  I have this file which I can consume.  It is created when a salesforce object changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
 <notifications xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
  <OrganizationId>00D30000000opwSEAQ</OrganizationId>
  <ActionId>04k30000000L6QPAA0</ActionId>
  <SessionId xsi:nil="true"/>
  <EnterpriseUrl>https://na1-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/22.0/00D30000000opwS</EnterpriseUrl>
  <PartnerUrl>https://na1-api.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/22.0/00D30000000opwS</PartnerUrl>
  <Notification>
   <Id>04l3000000JbKClAAN</Id>
   <sObject xsi:type="sf:Account" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <sf:Id>0013000000ooziWAAQ</sf:Id>
    <sf:BillingCity>New York</sf:BillingCity>
    <sf:BillingCountry>US</sf:BillingCountry>
    <sf:BillingPostalCode>10000</sf:BillingPostalCode>
    <sf:BillingState>New York</sf:BillingState>
    <sf:BillingStreet>302 E xxx St Apt C</sf:BillingStreet>
    <sf:FN__Mapping_Status__c>Not Located Yet</sf:FN__Mapping_Status__c>
    <sf:IsDeleted>false</sf:IsDeleted>
    <sf:Member_Status__c>Active</sf:Member_Status__c>
    <sf:Name>Joel Test</sf:Name>
   </sObject>
  </Notification>
 </notifications>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to parse it so that I can take the values in the sf namespace and update a database.  I can use SimpleXML to read stuff no in namespace, but I haven't been able to read namespace values.  Can someone point me to example code or tutorial on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that is a SOAP message from the Outbound Messaging feature in Salesforce. Instead of treating it as just XML, try using the native [PHP SoapServer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php) with the WSDL provided in Salesforce, as it is designed to handle SOAP messages like this. You can get the WSDL at Setup | Create | Workflow & Approvals | Outbound Messages |  | Endpoint WSDL. You might also want to look at the [Salesforce PHP Client](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapserver.php), which uses the corresponding PHP SoapClient and has a utility for handling the sf: namespace and converting to a SObject object. It shouldn't be too hard to rewire the toolkit to act as a server instead of a client so you can handle the Outbound Messages.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's SimpleXML will not work for reading namespace information. See this - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp . Instead try something like this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parser-create-ns.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP's SimpleXML may work for the case. Just need to use children() and use the right syntax.

Therefore, to read the field value BillingCity in Salesforce Outbound Message, you may use following code:

```
$rcXML->children('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')->Body->children('http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound')->notifications->Notification->sObject->children('urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com')->BillingCity
```

To help you understand how it works, I write a post with sames code and xml which shall be easier to understand.

http://amigotechnotes.wordpress.com/2013/11/16/parse-xml-with-namespace-by-simplexml-in-php/

Once you may read the filed value, you may store it to other database or text file with PHP.